# How do I match two ids against the same value (SQL)

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have a SQL question.

Say I have three tables:

Table 1: Artist

```
id bandid name
1  1      Paul McCartney
2  1      Ringo Starr
3  1      John Lennon
4  1      George Harrison
5  2      Mick Jagger
6  2      Keith Richards
7  2      Charlie Watts
8  2      Ronnie Wood
9  3      Travis Barker
10 3      Tom Delonge
11 3      Mark Hoppus
```

Table 2: Band

```
bandid bandname
1      the beatles
2      rolling stones
3      blink 182
```

Table 3: Artist on Album

```
albumid artistid
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       2
2       3
2       4
3       5
3       6
3       7
```

I'm seeking to count the number of albums two artists have worked together on, listing artist #1 and artist #2 names, the band they are both in, and the number of albums between them, while using an subquery. Another note: listing artist #1 against artist #2 is not a duplicate to listing artist #2 against artist #1.

Comment: The final portion of your question requiring both artist `1-2` and `2-1` to be reported separately makes no sense, and may be your own misinterpretation of the problem.  The artist on album junction table itself only records each artist relationship once per album.  Therefore, reporting this twice does not follow the original data.

Comment: So the original version of the question clarifies that two tuples containing [artist1, artist2] and [artist2, artist1] are two different results and not considered duplicates. I can post the original wording to the question?

Comment: Your junction table does contain these duplicates, and I can't imagine why you would have this requirement.  If you do have this requirement, then update the junction table to contain duplicate relationships.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How would I go about adding a subquery to the statement and attain the same result set?

Answer (score 0):

A self join is one approach here:

```sql
SELECT a1.name, a2.name, COUNT(*) AS num_shared_albums
FROM ArtistOnAlbum al1
INNER JOIN ArtistOnAlbum al2
    ON al1.albumid = al2.albumid AND
       al1.artistid < al2.artistid
INNER JOIN Artist a1
    ON al1.artistid = a1.id
INNER JOIN Artist a2
    ON al2.artistid = a2.id
GROUP BY
    a1.id, a2.id;
```

### Demo

Comment: Oh nice! That sort of works, but I need both [Paul McCartney, Ringo Starr] and [Ringo Starr, Paul McCartney] tuples, and the answer requires some kind of subquery involved. I'm guessing it's passing artistid IN to something, but I don't know where to go from there. I have a larger, different version of this question, and I can get the count of number of times two ID (like artistid) matching against a value (albumid) from a single table but i cant seem to get these values to link up with a name from the artist table, which I'm guessing is done through passing artistid into an IN clause

Comment: ...your requirement makes no sense, and artist A working with artist B should be reported once as A-B.